# Shouldn't the Super-Soldier serum in The Incredible Hulk been frozen?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk-2008

In "The Incredible Hulk" (2008) we see Ross open a "CryoSync" container that is consistent with one storing biological samples in liquid nitrogen (incl. vapor pressure relief). Now, i noticed the "serum" he took out was a liquid. What is liquid at that temperature, i wondered?

I looked and was able to find only 2 things: nitrogen (unsurprisingly) and oxygen. Everything else at -196 C is either solid - or still a gas (helium, hydrogen). Sooo... it seems the serum can only be a mixture of liquified oxygen and nitrogen! :)

Wouldn't a "proper" serum been frozen instead?

Comment: Good question, wrong spot for it.

Comment: @Möoz - what be the right spot for it?! I figured "suspension of disbelief" discussion is ok

Comment: yes, those questions are ok, but not asking for actual scientific answers (out-of-universe). Interestingly though, you could ask about in-universe scientific explanations (which in this case would just be 'it's just the way it is').

Comment: @Möoz - it's never black&white though. The in-universe and out-of-universe realities largely overlap - or we won't be able to understand/relate. There are also limits to how much one is able to suspend disbelief and still stay engaged. Which is why we look for explanations of questions like this. It's like saying religion is always immiscible with science. Not so.

Comment: “What is liquid at that temperature, i wondered? I looked and was able to find only 2 things: nitrogen (unsurprisingly) and oxygen.” Looks like you’ve figured out the super-soldier serum recipe!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities here that you may have overlooked.

- Noting the elaborate setup between the liquid nitrogen tanks and the cryo-storage container, the nitrogen might be being allowed to enter its [*vapor phase*](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28424/why-are-cell-lines-frozen-in-vapor-phase) before being channeled into the tank. This would mean that the serum is being held at a substantially higher temperature (between -140°C and -180°C) than pure liquid nitrogen (-196°C).
- There are several dozen complex substances that are known to remain liquid at just *under* -196°C, for example [N,N-diethylmethylamine](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27027/lowest-freezing-point-room-temperature-liquid). If you raise the temperature just another 10 degree, that number goes into the hundreds.
- As to whether the coldness of the serum substance would kill Blonsky, it's certainly possible (indeed probable) that it took the General a few minutes to travel from the basement to the operating theatre, thus allowing the serum to heat up to a useable temperature.

Comment: Excellent answer! You restore my faith in Marvel's functional universe :). I had no idea there are complex compounds that stay liquid to temperatures so low.